# Embedding Wiremock in Spring Boot application when running in dev mode

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I've used Wiremock for my integration tests in SpringBoot using @AutoConfigureWireMock & random ports and it works well.

Now I want to use it in embedded way just the way we use embedded Tomcat, Jetty etc in SpringBoot running in dev mode. This means if I run my app using Gradle's bootTestRun task I want Wiremock to automatically start as well. This means I don't have to separately start standalone Wiremock beforehand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

SetNug